# Why do Op amps need dedicated grounds to source?

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, transistors, grounding

According to the author of this schematic the bias currents will not flow without a power supply-input signal common ground. I don't understand why the bias currents wouldn't just flow into the negative terminals of the voltage source even without a dedicated ground.

I would be really grateful for any pointers.

[image]

Comment: Currents always flow in loops. *why the bias currents wouldn't just flow into the negative terminals of the voltage source* Where would you then connect the negative terminal of the voltage source? I suggest that you draw this (start on paper) and see if there is a **loop** where the bias current can flow. If there is no loop, the current cannot flow.

Comment: How many opamps have you seen with a +V pin, -V pin, and a GND pin? where the GND is actually involved with the analog pins (not auxiliary digital functions)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I don't understand why the bias currents wouldn't just flow into the
> negative terminals of the voltage source even without a dedicated
> ground.*

They would. They will find a way to flow (out of the bases) into a more negative voltage whether it be ground (0 volts) or the negative rail or somewhere slightly more negative that the common-emitter point of the transistors.

If there is no connection to the bases or, the connection is to a voltage higher than the common emitter node, then bias currents (for this particular op-amp you sketched) won't flow.

Comment: Thank you for the answer again Andy. Two questions in one day! Sorry I'm taking of your time, but this is all very confusing at times!

Comment: No problem @ZhelyazkoGrudov